# How to force user to always login when hitting an [Authorize] endpoint

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my Asp.net mvc application I'm using `[Authorize]` on several of my controllers. When the user is hitting one of the controllers the `[Authorize]` header will redirect the user to the login page, the user will authorize and get access to the controller.

Now the user will be remembered by my application. But what I want is that the user should always need to login when using one of my `[Authorize]` controllers.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do your users navigate between controllers? would you have them log in everytime the controller changes?

Comment: No I don't navigate between controllers. Everytime a user hits an [Authorize] endpoint they will need to sign in again.

Comment: ok, could you have a role for each controller. at the point of login could you assign the user to the `controller role` (and remove any other previous `controller roles`). Set the required role on each controller's `Authorize` attribute. When the user hits a new one they'll be sent to login. I imagine you could do the same w/ claims

Comment: Seems more like a workaround approach, isn't there a setting for this in the mvc framework?

Comment: I'm not sure. This would be an 'out of the box' approach for Roles I think (for what you need to do). MS even allude to it on their example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2 with `ControlPanelUser` role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like adding an `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();` at the end of the pipelined fixed it.